# Apache Hbase installation

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to install Hbase(hbase-0.94.8) in ubuntu 12.04 enviroment.

I followed exactly the same steps given in this page

http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html

I am able to start Hbase and enter into shell but when i type "create 'test', 'cf'" from shell the following ERRORS were thrown

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'test', 'cf'
13/06/11 13:01:40 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:41 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:42 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:44 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:46 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:50 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/06/11 13:01:54 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Here is some help for this command:
Create table; pass table name, a dictionary of specifications per
column family, and optionally a dictionary of table configuration.
Dictionaries are described below in the GENERAL NOTES section.
Examples:

  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
  hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true}
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']}
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {SPLITS_FILE => 'splits.txt'}
  hbase> # Optionally pre-split the table into NUMREGIONS, using
  hbase> # SPLITALGO ("HexStringSplit", "UniformSplit" or classname)
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}
```

Please anyone explain me what is issue with this installation.

Regards,
Rayappan A

Comment: can you show me the contents of your hbase-site.xml and hmaster log file.

Comment: <configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///tmp/hbase-hduser/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/DIRECTORY/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

Comment: I would like to have a look at your log file once.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///home/ishwarya/hbase-store</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/ishwarya/zookeeper</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2182</value>
        <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
                     The port at which the clients will connect.</description>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and use the code markup to make this readable.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error to correct it go to  hbase-site.xml in conf folder and remove the comments before and after property tag(`<!-- -->`).

This is my hbase.site.xml file you can compare it with yours.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the HMaster has to be started. You can do that using webUI.Use cloudera manager to webUi to start the hbase master. Then it will work fine